Why is two way bind value not working? Maui Blazor Hybrid app
I am still having a hard time binding to a simple label.  The issue seems simple, but I've wasted days so it's time to ask for help.  Maybe someone knows the answer.
In the code bellow, the button works every time but pressing Enter does not update the page even though the variabled binded to the label has changed (I've checked by printing to the console using Serilog)
In short: the button and the enter key, correctly call the exact same function, which does the job every time. Unfortunately the page only senses a change with the button by changing the status of the label.
Now, if I press Enter twice then it seems to work, but it's not showing you that in the background there is an exception because it's a duplicate value already.  Press Enter a third time and then you get the correct status.
Please keep in mind that I am new to C#, specially to Maui Blazor Hybrid apps.
Thank you!
html:

<div>
<button @onclick=PushToDatabaseFunction> upload to db </button>

 <input @onkeyup="@(e => KeyPressHandler("inputFieldForUploading", e))"
                @bind-value:event="oninput"
                @bind-value="inputFieldString" 
             type="text" 
             placeholder="..." /> 
</div>

<div>
          <label>Status Label: @statusLabelBindString</label> 
</div>


On my code:

private string statusLabelBindString = ""; 
private string inputFieldString = "";


private async void KeyPressHandler(string inputField, KeyboardEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Key == "Enter")
    {
        if (inputField == "inputFieldForUploading")
            await PushToDatabaseFunction();
        
    }
     }

private async Task PushToDatabaseFunction() {  

//code here takes the inputFieldString and adds it to a database   
//I've triple checked many many times and the code to the db works correctly

await db.insertAsync(inputFieldString);     

 //the following line also works correctly, as the statusLabelBindString  variable >  
// takes on a new value. 

 if(db.status=="ok")
   statusLabelBindString = $" {inputFieldString} was added to db";
 else
   statusLabelBindString = "Error - Duplicate value";

//Even though statusLabelBindString has a new value (I've checked), the label does not
//update if you press Enter, but from the button it works fine.  



    }


What could be the matter?
Thank you!

To be clear, I have tried many different combinations.  I also understand that there is a function called StateHasChanged() that renders the screen again but I've had mixed results.  I feel that I'm missing something rather basic.  Thank you!

Have you tried making your attribute public?

Yes @FaheemAnis !
It simply does not work when being called through the KeyHandlerFunction.  I am very suspicious that this is a timing issue with the variable not updating due to focus on the element, but man it sure it's hard to find the true reason.

First of all, I reproduced you problem with the await Task.Delay(1000);:
private async Task PushToDatabaseFunction() {  
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   statusLabelBindString = $" {inputFieldString} was added to db";
}

The code above can reproduce your problem. And I can fix it in two ways:

Call the StateHasChanged() manually, so you can also try it:

if(db.status=="ok")
{
   statusLabelBindString = $" {inputFieldString} was added to db";
   StateHasChanged();
}
 else{
   statusLabelBindString = "Error - Duplicate value";
   StateHasChanged();
}


Delete the await in await Task.Delay(1000);:

private async Task PushToDatabaseFunction() {  
   Task.Delay(1000);
   statusLabelBindString = $" {inputFieldString} was added to db";
}

The two ways can bot update the label when you press the Enter first time.

If you don't want to use the StateHasChanged(), you can just make the KeyPressHandler as async Task instead of async void.

private async Task KeyPressHandler(string inputField, KeyboardEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Key == "Enter")
    {
        if (inputField == "inputFieldForUploading")
            await PushToDatabaseFunction();
        
    }
}

When you use async void, UI is never refreshed (re-rendered) because the StateHasChanged() is never being called by the runtime because the runtime didn't know when the async methods called return. But the Task will let the runtime know when the method return. So use async Task instead of async void.

Thank you very much @Liyun Zhang - MSFT !!!
One thing I forgot to mention is that the method db.Insert() is async, so I can't really get rid of the await there.  The code example should had been written as "await db.insertAsync()"
I did add the StateHasChanged() and it works, but this is still driving me crazy.  The code is the same but why does it not render when called from inside another function?
It's like painting a car red, and writing on top of the paint "This car is red."  Kind of redundant.

Please check the 3rd method in my updated answer. @BMET1

you are the man!  All of the solutions you provided worked, but the third one really hit home for me.  It has been a learning experience for me.  Thank you very much for taking the time.
